# How to rotate a canvas box using keyboard?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I've been wondering if there is a way to turn a canvas box using the keyboard without using animations.

I would like to press the key `E` to turn my box clockwise, and key `Q` should turn it counter-clockwise. As I said before, using **no animations**.

If you would like to see exactly what I'm working on, and the context where it should be done, here is a link http://cssdeck.com/labs/collab/stexplorer

and just in case, I'll post my code here too!

If you use this code, notice that I want it to be able to turn **and** move forward at the **same time**.

```js
$(function() {
  var n = 3;
  var xD = 0;
  var yD = 0;
  var btn = undefined;
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

  function resizeCanvas() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    render(); 
  }

  var ss = {
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0,
    "width": 100,
    "height": 75
  };

  function render() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.rect(ss.x, ss.y, ss.width, ss.height);
 ctx.lineWidth = 1;
 ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
 ctx.stroke();
  }

  function move() {
 x = ss.x + (xD * n);
 y = ss.y + (yD * n);
    ss.x = x;
    ss.y = y;
    render();
  }

  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if(btn !== undefined){ 
      return;
    }

    // shoot (space):32
    // left
 xD = e.which == 37 ? -1 : xD;
    xD = e.which == 65 ? -1 : xD;
    // up
 yD = e.which == 38 ? -1 : yD;
    yD = e.which == 87 ? -1 : yD;
    // right
 xD = e.which == 39 ? 1 : xD;
    xD = e.which == 68 ? 1 : xD;
    // down
 yD = e.which == 40 ? 1 : yD;
 yD = e.which == 83 ? 1 : yD;
    // clockwise e:69
    // counter-clockwise q: 81
    // zoom-out f:70
    // zoom-in r:82

    btn = e.which;
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.which === btn){
      btn = undefined;
    }

    // shoot (space):32
    // left
 xD = e.which == 37 ? 0 : xD;
    xD = e.which == 65 ? 0 : xD;
    // up
 yD = e.which == 38 ? 0 : yD;
    yD = e.which == 87 ? 0 : yD;
    // right
 xD = e.which == 39 ? 0 : xD;
    xD = e.which == 68 ? 0 : xD;
    // down
 yD = e.which == 40 ? 0 : yD;
    yD = e.which == 83 ? 0 : yD;
    // clockwise e:69
    // counter-clockwise q: 81
    // zoom-out f:70
    // zoom-in r:82

    e.preventDefault();
  });

  resizeCanvas();
  render();
  setInterval(move, .01);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#canvas {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the rect to rotate around it's centerpoint, you must:

- Set the rotation point to the center of the rect using `context.translate`
- Rotate the canvas using `context.rotate`
- Draw the rect

Here's (untested) example code:

```
var accumRotation=0;

// now change the accumRotation using the E & Q keys
// on key-E do rotate(Math.PI/2); and render();
// on key-Q do rotate(-Math.PI/2); and render();

function rotate(additionalRotation){
    accumRotation+=additionalRotation;
}

function render() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    // translate to the centerpoint of the rect
    // This sets the [0,0] origin of the canvas to the rect centerpoint
    // This will set the rotation point at the center of the rect
    var cx=ss.x+ss.width/2;
    var cy=ss.y+ss.height/2;
    ctx.translate(cx,cy);
    // rotate
    ctx.rotate(accumRotation);
    // draw the rect
    ctx.beginPath();
    // since [0,0] is at center rect, you must pull the rect drawing
    // leftward & upward by half the rect width & height
    ctx.rect(-ss.width/2, -ss.height/2, ss.width, ss.height);
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
    ctx.stroke();
    // always clean up by unrotating & untranslating
    ctx.rotate(-accumRotation);
    ctx.translate(-cx,-cy);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the rotating a little more fluid? Which is what I was searching for

Comment: Increment the rotation by a very small amount.

Comment: For example: `accumRotation+=Math.PI/30;`

Comment: I understand what you wrote, I just don't know where to write it... sorry but could you please be patient and tell me what I'm replacing with what? thanks...

Comment: `function rotate(additionalRotation){ accumRotation += additionalRotation; }` is replaced with `function rotate(additionalRotation){ accumRotation += Math.PI/30;}` Good luck with your project!