# change up movement depending on rotation

Tags: javascript, canvas, rotation

This question is related to [How to rotate a canvas box using keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282681/how-to-rotate-a-canvas-box-using-keyboard/)

If you read the question, you know that I'm trying to make a box rotate with the keyboard.

The box can as well move left, up, right and down. And my most current version can also turn. But the problem is:

- **When the box turns, it doesn't change the way it moves.**

In other words: let's say that you press `W`, it moves forwards, while you press `W` you press "E". Now **the square** moves clockwise. You turn it 90 degrees clockwise, you now press `W`.

But what happens to the box? It doesn't move *right*! It moves *up*!

This is an undesired effect. When the box is rotated 90 degrees clockwise and you press `W`,**it should** move to the *right*.

**ALSO**:
When I press `Q` or `E` it does rotate, but only once. I would like it to rotate for as long as the key is pressed, and once you release the key, it should stop spinning.

I'm new to canvas, so I don't have not even the slightest idea of how to do this.

My code is here: http://cssdeck.com/labs/collab/stexplorer

And here:

```js
$(function() {
  var n = 3;
  var xD = 0;
  var yD = 0;
  var btn = undefined;
  var accumRotation = 0;

  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

  function resizeCanvas() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    render(); 
  }

  var ss = {
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0,
    "width": 100,
    "height": 75
  };

  function rotate(additionalRotation) {
    accumRotation += Math.PI / 180;
  }

  function render() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var cx = ss.x + ss.width / 2;
    var cy = ss.y + ss.height / 2;
    ctx.translate(cx, cy);
    ctx.rotate(accumRotation);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(-ss.width / 2, -ss.height / 2, ss.width, ss.height);
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.rotate(-accumRotation);
    ctx.translate(-cx, -cy);
  }

  function move() {
    x = ss.x + (xD * n);
    y = ss.y + (yD * n);
    ss.x = x;
    ss.y = y;
    render();
  }

  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if(btn !== undefined){ 
      return;
    }

    // shoot (space):32
    // left
    xD = e.which == 37 ? -1 : xD;
    xD = e.which == 65 ? -1 : xD;
    // up
    yD = e.which == 38 ? -1 : yD;
    yD = e.which == 87 ? -1 : yD;
    // right
    xD = e.which == 39 ? 1 : xD;
    xD = e.which == 68 ? 1 : xD;
    // down
    yD = e.which == 40 ? 1 : yD;
    yD = e.which == 83 ? 1 : yD;
    // clockwise e:69
    if(e.which == 69) {
      rotate(Math.PI / 2);
      render();
    }
    // counter-clockwise q: 81
    if(e.which == 81) {
      rotate(-Math.PI / 2);
      render();
    }
    // zoom-out f:70
    // zoom-in r:82

    btn = e.which;
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.which === btn){
      btn = undefined;
    }

    // shoot (space):32
    // left
    xD = e.which == 37 ? 0 : xD;
    xD = e.which == 65 ? 0 : xD;
    // up
    yD = e.which == 38 ? 0 : yD;
    yD = e.which == 87 ? 0 : yD;
    // right
    xD = e.which == 39 ? 0 : xD;
    xD = e.which == 68 ? 0 : xD;
    // down
    yD = e.which == 40 ? 0 : yD;
    yD = e.which == 83 ? 0 : yD;
    // clockwise e:69
    // counter-clockwise q: 81
    // zoom-out f:70
    // zoom-in r:82

    e.preventDefault();
  });

  resizeCanvas();
  render();
  setInterval(move, .01);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#canvas {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: why did you use `setInterval` in the `keyup` listener? it makes the animation laggy when switching direction

Comment: @micnic epcept I didn't... Where exactly?

Comment: `setInterval(move, .01);` last line in the js code

Comment: @micnic yeah, what about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser will not report 2+ different keys being pressed simultaneously (except for augmenting keys like Ctrl, Shift, etc).

So when you press and hold "W" to move rightward and then also press "E" to rotate clockwise, the browser will **stop issuing W-keydown events** and start issuing E-keydown events.

- Press W: events are multiple W-keydowns.
- Press E without releasing W: events are multiple E-keydowns (no more W-keydowns)
- Release W: event is one W-keyup.
- Release E: event is one E-keyup.

So if you want your rect to simultaneously move & rotate, you would set/clear a `Wkey` flag on W keydown/keyup events and you would set/clear an `Ekey` flag on E keydown/keyup events.

- Set Wkey=true on W-keydown,
- Set Wkey=false on W-keyup,
- Set Ekey=true on E-keydown,
- Set Ekey=false on E-keyup.

*Then handle all your flags in one single timer loop*. Just check each flag and do the appropriate actions. This flag method will let you simultaneously move and rotate.

- if(Wkey){ move right }
- if(Ekey){ rotate clockwise }

**[ Added example code and Demo per request ]**

```js
// create canvas related variables
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

ctx.fillStyle='skyblue';
ctx.strokeStyle='lightgray'
ctx.lineWidth=3;

// set canvas to be a tab stop (necessary to give it focus)
canvas.setAttribute('tabindex','0');

// set focus to the canvas
canvas.focus();

var Wkey=false;
var Ekey=false;
var x=25;
var y=50;
var width=50;
var height=35;
var rotation=0;

// start the animation
requestAnimationFrame(draw);

// listen for keydown events on the document
// the canvas does not trigger key events
document.addEventListener("keydown",handleKeydown,false);
document.addEventListener("keyup",handleKeyup,false);

// handle key events
function handleKeydown(e){

  // if the canvas isn't focused,
  // let some other element handle this key event
  //            if(e.target.id!=='canvas'){return;}

  // set flags true on keydown
  switch(e.keyCode){
    case 69: Ekey=true; break;  // E
    case 87: Wkey=true; break;  // W
  } 
}


// handle key events
function handleKeyup(e){

  // if the canvas isn't focused,
  // let some other element handle this key event
  //            if(e.target.id!=='canvas'){return;}

  // set flags false on keyup
  switch(e.keyCode){
    case 69: Ekey=false; break;  // E
    case 87: Wkey=false; break;  // W
  } 
}


// clear the canvas and redraw the rect 
// in its new x,y position at its new rotation
function draw(){
  // move if W is down
  if(Wkey){x++;}
  // rotate if E is down
  if(Ekey){rotation+=Math.PI/180;}
  // draw the rect at x,y with rotation
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx.translate(x,y);
  ctx.rotate(rotation);
  ctx.fillRect(-width/2,-height/2,width,height);
  ctx.rotate(-rotation);
  ctx.translate(-x,-y);
  // request another loop
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Press W to move rightward. Press E to rotate clockwise.</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=125></canvas>
```

Comment: But this doesn not change the direction of movment

Comment: Sure it will! For example, (1) press W and the keydown event sets  `Wkey=true`. The timing loop will move the rect until `Wkey` becomes false due to W-keyup, (2) press E while W is still held down and the keydown  event sets `Ekey=true`. The timing loop will both move and rotate the rect because `Wkey` and `Ekey` are both true. ;-)

Comment: Oh... You are right! Wait... I'm confused... Could you please add some code? It is very confusing for me, thank you!

Comment: Done...Good luck with your project!